# A start job is running for dev-disk-by -- BUT fstab is fine

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, mount

I am setting up a new root partition on /dev/sda2  (newer Fedora 25)
I have done this before and had no problems in the past.
(If you realy need to know how see [Fedora on New Root Partition](http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/usage/fedora_on_new_partition.txt)

This time however I get a "A start job is running for dev-disk-by..."
error during the boot sequence.

It cannot be the UUID problems as I don't use them.

This is the /etc/fstab of the new root partition...

```
#
# /etc/fstab
#
#/dev/sda1 /        xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/sda2 /        ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/sda5 /home    xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/sda3 swap     swap    defaults        0 0
```

Everything checks out.  The FS types are correct.  In fact this is the same "/etc/fstab" used on the previous (and working root partition, just with "/dev/sda1" as "/" and "/dev/sda2" as "/mnt/alt"

But I still get that error, hanging basically forever (I let it go for an hour!) As such every other answer I have seen is useless!

Answer (score 0):

Boot a live installer and mount the install (including /boot and /dev,/proc/sys and chroot back in and rerun a dracut --regenerate-all --force && grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2.cfg and then retry.  The rational here is that teh grub image is still looking for the old data as it and the initramfs|initrd were never updated to look at the new locations and mappings.

Comment: The point of installing directly into an alternative root partition, is to avoid the requirement to set up a DVD (which the system does not have) or a USB stick.  That is basically get the system in a working state before booting from the old to new system.   Also keeping the old system in perfectly working (default) state while testing the new system, until you are ready for a full switch.

So how can I get it to boot the old system and clear that confusion.  Which did not happen on other systems I have done this with!

Comment: So how can I... set up the full chroot using the new root... so I can then properly regenerate the initial RAM disk